# create multidimensional array while taking the input from postman with same keyword - Node Express

Tags: node.js, express

if I take the `image` keyword for n number of times in a Postman with multiple files as values can I store it in a multi-dimensional array in nested form.

for eg:

```
[[1,2,3], [2,4], [9,5,3,1]....n]
```

in Postman
[image]

first `image` keyword has 3 file and second one has 2 files and it continues

```
const uploads = require("../../midddlewares/uploads").array("image", 20);
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // image
    uploads(req, res, async (err) => {
      if (!req.files || req.files == "") {
        const updated_response = setErrorResponseMsg(
          RESPONSE.PARAMETER_IS_MANDATORY,
          "Image"
        );
        return send(res, updated_response);
      } else if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        return send(res, RESPONSE.FILE_SIZE);
      }
      if (err) {
        return send(res, RESPONSE.UNKNOWN_ERROR);
      }
      let filenames = [];
      if (req.files != null) {
        req.files.forEach((ele) => {
          filenames.push(ele.filename);
        });
      }
      console.log(filenames);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return send(res, RESPONSE.UNKNOWN_ERROR);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

for this code i get the o/p like

```
[
  '1698230844546.png',
  '1698230844547.png',
  '1698230844547.png',
  '1698230844549.png',
  '1698230844550.png'
]
```

but I need o/p like

```
[
  ['1698230844546.png',
  '1698230844547.png',
  '1698230844548.png'],
  ['1698230844549.png',
  '1698230844550.png']
]
```